# Powershell: Copy folders with only one specific child item

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to copy a folder to another place using powershell with only specific file format children.

I have a folder `ec-alert-service` which has subfolders and files, it has one `.txt` file. I want to copy this folder to another location with only that `txt` file

So I wrote this command, but it is not copying the text file but just empty folder. So basically the `-Filter` is not working

```
Copy-Item -Path D:\Pawan\Gitlab\ec-alert-service -Filter *.txt -Destination D:\Pawan\GitlabBuildFiles
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding -Recurse?

Comment: Try this: `Copy-Item -Path D:\Pawan\Gitlab\ec-alert-service\* -Filter *.txt -Destination D:\Pawan\GitlabBuildFiles`

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld - It just copied the file but not folder.

Comment: @PalleDue - Yes. Recurse copied everything

Answer (score 0):

```
$splatPrm = @{
    sourceDirectory = "d:\tmp\001"
    destinationDirectory = "D:\tmp\002"
    wildCardArray = @("*.txt") # or @("*.txt", "*.csv") or other
}

& {
    param(
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$sourceDirectory,
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$destinationDirectory,
        [string[]]$wildCardArray
    )
    $pathToCopy = [System.IO.Path]::Join($destinationDirectory.FullName, $sourceDirectory.Name)
    if (-not [System.IO.Directory]::Exists($pathToCopy)){
        [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($pathToCopy)
    }
    foreach ($wildCard in $wildCardArray){
        foreach ($file in $sourceDirectory.GetFiles($wildCard)){
            $file.CopyTo([System.IO.Path]::Join($pathToCopy, $file.Name))
        }
    }
} @splatPrm
```